# Integral of product log and square root $ \int_{-2}^2 \log(a-bx)\sqrt{4-x^2} dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to compute the following integral as a function of the parameters $a$ and $b$
$$
\int_{-2}^2 \log(a-bx)\sqrt{4-x^2} dx
$$

But, I don't know how I should deal with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where do this problem come from? Why do you need to solve for $a,b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-t^2} dt=\frac\pi2$, rewrite the integral as

$$
I = \int_{-2}^2 \log(a-bx)\sqrt{4-x^2} dx
\overset{x= 2t}= 2\pi \log a + 4J\left(\frac{2b}a\right)
$$
where

$$J(p)= \int_{-1}^1 \log(1-pt )\sqrt{1-t^2} dt
$$
$$J’(p)= -\int_{-1}^1 \frac{ t\sqrt{1-t^2}}{ 1-pt} dt=-\frac{\pi}{2p^3}\left(1-\sqrt{1-p^2}\right)^2
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
I & = 2\pi \log a + 4\int_0^{\frac{2b}a}J’(p)dp\\
&= 2\pi \log a + 2\pi \left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-p^2}+1}+\ln\left(1+\sqrt{1-p^2}\right)\right)\bigg|_0^{\frac{2b}a}\\
 &= 2\pi \left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-4b^2}+a} +\ln \left({\sqrt{a^2-4b^2}+a}\right) -\frac12 -\ln2\right)
\end{align}