# Definite Integral $\int_{1-\sqrt{a}}^{1+\sqrt{a}} \ln(1-z t^2)\frac{\sqrt{4a-(t^2-1-a)^2}}{t}\, dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Suppose $z<\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{a})^2}$, $0<a<1$. I need to compute the following integral as function of z:
$$
I(z)= \int_{1-\sqrt{a}}^{1+\sqrt{a}} \ln(1-z t^2)\frac{\sqrt{4a-(t^2-1-a)^2}}{t}\, dt
$$

So far, following the trick in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4003465/849135) I defined
$$
J'(p)=\int_{1-\sqrt{a}}^{1+\sqrt{a}} \frac{t}{p t^2 -1}\sqrt{4a-(t^2-1-a)^2}\, dt
$$
With the change of variable $t^2-1-a = x$,
$$
J'(p)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-2\sqrt{a}}^{2\sqrt{a}} \frac{\sqrt{4a-x^2}}{px + p(a+1)-1}\, dx
$$
Doing the Euler substitution $x = 2\sqrt{a}\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$, we have (using Mathematica)
$$
J'(p) = 16 a \int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{(t^2+1)^2 \bigg( \Big[p\big(\sqrt{a}+1\big)^2-1\Big]t^2+p\big(\sqrt{a}-1)^2-1\bigg)} \, dt
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
J'(p) &= 16 a \int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2}{(t^2+1)^2 \bigg( \Big[p\big(\sqrt{a}+1\big)^2-1\Big]t^2+p\big(\sqrt{a}-1)^2-1\bigg)} \, dt \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{-1+p(a+1)+\Big(1-\big(\sqrt{a}-1\big)^2p\Big)\sqrt{\frac{-1+\big(\sqrt{a}+1\big)^2p}{-1+\big(\sqrt{a}-1\big)^2p}}}{p^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now, to find $I(z) = \int_0^z J'(p) \, dp$, there is a problem that in the $J'(p)$ there is a logarithm of $p$ which makes it undefined at 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the substitution $x=\frac{ t^2-1-a}{2\sqrt a}$, along with the shorthands $p= \frac{2z\sqrt a}{1-z-az}$, $q= \frac{1+a}{2\sqrt a} $, the integral simplifies to
\begin{align}
I(z)=& \int_{1-\sqrt{a}}^{1+\sqrt{a}} \ln(1-z t^2)\frac{\sqrt{4a-(t^2-1-a)^2}}{t}\, dt\\
=& \sqrt a\int_{-1}^1 [\ln(1-z-az)+\ln (1-p x)]\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{q+x}dx \\
= & \>\pi a\ln(1-z-az)+\sqrt a \>J(p)
\end{align}
where $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{ \sqrt{1-x^2}}{q+x}dx = \pi \sqrt a$ is used and

\begin{align}
 J(s) =&\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\ln (1-s x) \sqrt{1-x^2}}{q+x}dx \\
J’(s)=& -\int_{-1}^1 
\frac{x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-s x)(q+x)}dx \\
=& \frac1{1+sq}\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{q\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x+q}- \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-s x}\right)dx\\
= & \frac\pi{1+sq}\left(\frac{1+a}2
-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2} \right)
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
I(z)=& \>a\pi \ln(1-z-az)+\sqrt a \int_0^p J’(s)ds
 = - \pi\sqrt{a} \int_0^p \frac{1-\sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2(1+sq)} ds\\
= &- \pi\sqrt{a}\bigg[ \sqrt{q^2-1} \> \bigg(\tanh^{-1}\frac{p+q}{\sqrt{(q^2-1)(1-p^2)}}
  - \tanh^{-1} \frac{q}{\sqrt{q^2-1}}\bigg)
\\& \hspace{9mm}-q\,{\rm \tanh^{-1}}\sqrt{1-p^2} 
+ q \ln\frac{2(1+pq)}{p} +\frac{\sqrt{1-p^2}-1}p \bigg]
\end{align}

Comment: I edited your answer, since your answer had some formal flaws. I left the last integral unevaluated, since the answer is complicated.

Comment: @Diger - Thanks for the correction. I’ll complete it.

Comment: I just edited again. sry, maybe just double check.

Comment: Maybe the logarithmic singularity at $p=0$ he is refering to, is the second bracket, but it actually cancels out.

Comment: when you modified it again, you introduced some new errors^^

Comment: @Diger - I checked the modification carefully; quite sure it is right

Comment: Thanks for the work. But, there is still a problem. In the last expression, the term tanh^{-1}q/(\sqrt(q^2-1)) is a complex number, because the argument is larger than 1. But I(z) should be a real number.

Comment: @Rostam22 - you may write $arctanh(x)= -i \pi/2 - arctanh(1/x)$ to avoid cancel the imaginary part

Comment: @Quanto: Just wondering why you expressed the arctanh the way they are as you'd expect real numbers which it clearly isn't apriori as $\frac{p+q}{\sqrt{(q^2-1)(1-p^2)}}>1$ inside the arctanh. It may not be wrong, but clearly not beneficial. Not sure why you changed it this way as it was "correct" before.

Comment: @Diger - I only verified numerically that the result was correct. It didn’t occur to me that the term was implicitly complex until Rostam22 pointed out. It should’ve been other way around to avoid confusion.